# jQuery Memory Skill game setTimeout() issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a little game of [Simon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_(game)) with jQuery. I have the functionality I want; start on page load, score, round numbers, etc, and the game works to an extent.

However, I still have a problem that I can't get my head around. I want to be able to prevent the user from being able to select the panels during the computer's turn. Currently, the user can trigger a sequence during the computer displaying its output, which causes havoc with buttons flashing and sounds going off.

The issue lies in `setTimeout()`. I tried to implement a variable 'cpuLoop' which turns to true when it's the computer's turn, and then back to false, but the implementation of `setTimeout()` means that there are still events on the event loop even after `cpuLoop` has been changed to false. The change to false changes immediately when of course it should wait until the `setTimeout()` has completed.

A similar problem is encountered when the reset button is clicked. When clicked, it should interrupt the `setTimeout()` events and restart the game. As it is, it continues outputting the computer's turn.

To get around this, I have attached the `setTimeout()` functions in the global scope and attempted to cut them off with `clearInterval(var)` but this seems to have no effect at the moment.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(function(){

var counter = 0;
var cpuArray = [];
var cpuSlice = [];
var numArray = [];
var userArray = [];
var num = 1;
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;
var cpuLoop = false;

// Initialise the game
function init(){
    $('#roundNumber').html('1');
    counter = 0;
    cpuArray = [];
    numArray = [];
    userArray = [];
    cpuLoop = false;
    num = 1;

    // Create cpuArray
    function generateRandomNum(min, max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }

    for(var i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
        numArray.push(generateRandomNum(0, 4));
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++){
        switch(numArray[i]){
            case 0:
                cpuArray.push('a');
                break;
            case 1:
                cpuArray.push('b');
                break;
            case 2:
                cpuArray.push('c');
                break;
            case 3:
                cpuArray.push('d');
                break;
        }
    }
    console.log('cpuArray: ' + cpuArray);

    // Create  a subset of the array for comparing the user's choices
    cpuSlice = cpuArray.slice(0, num);
    goUpToPoint(cpuSlice);
}

init();

var looperA, looperB, looperC, looperD;

// Cpu plays sounds and lights up depending on cpuArray
function cpuPlayList(input, time){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(input === 'a'){
            looperA = setTimeout(function(){
                aSoundCpu.play();
                $('#a').fadeOut(1).fadeIn(500);
            }, time * 500);
        } else if(input === 'b'){
            looperB = setTimeout(function(){
                bSoundCpu.play();
                $('#b').fadeOut(1).fadeIn(500);
            }, time * 500);
        } else if(input === 'c'){
            looperC = setTimeout(function(){
                cSoundCpu.play();
                $('#c').fadeOut(1).fadeIn(500);
            }, time * 500);
        } else if(input === 'd'){
            looperD = setTimeout(function(){
                dSoundCpu.play();
                $('#d').fadeOut(1).fadeIn(500);
            }, time * 500);
        }
    }, 1750);
};

// CPU takes its turn
function goUpToPoint(arr){
    cpuLoop = true;
    console.log('cpuLoop: ' + cpuLoop);
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        cpuPlayList(arr[i], i);
    }
    cpuLoop = false;
    console.log('cpuLoop: ' + cpuLoop);

}

// User presses restart button
$('.btn-warning').click(function(){
    clearTimeout(looperA);
    clearTimeout(looperB);
    clearTimeout(looperC);
    clearTimeout(looperD);
    init();
});

// Array comparison helper
Array.prototype.equals = function (array) {
    // if the other array is a falsy value, return
    if (!array)
        return false;

    // compare lengths - can save a lot of time
    if (this.length != array.length)
        return false;

    for (var i = 0, l=this.length; i < l; i++) {
        // Check if we have nested arrays
        if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) {
            // recurse into the nested arrays
            if (!this[i].equals(array[i]))
                return false;
        }
        else if (this[i] != array[i]) {
            // Warning - two different object instances will never be equal: {x:20} != {x:20}
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// User presses one of the four main buttons
function buttonPress(val){

    console.log('strict?: ' + $('#strict').prop('checked'));
    console.log('cpuSlice: ' + cpuSlice);
    userArray.push(val);
    console.log('userArray: ' + userArray);
    if(val === 'a'){ aSoundCpu.play(); }
    if(val === 'b'){ bSoundCpu.play(); }
    if(val === 'c'){ cSoundCpu.play(); }
    if(val === 'd'){ dSoundCpu.play(); }

    // If the user selected an incorrect option
    if(val !== cpuSlice[counter])
        //Strict mode off
        if(!$('#strict').prop('checked')){
            // Strict mode off
            alert('WRONG! I\'ll show you again...');
            userArray = [];
            console.log('cpuSlice: ' + cpuSlice);
            goUpToPoint(cpuSlice);
            counter = 0;
        } else {
            //Strict mode on
            losses++;
            $('#lossCount').html(losses);
            ui_alert('You lose! New Game?');
            return;
    } else {
        // User guessed correctly
        counter++;
    }
    if(counter === cpuSlice.length){
        $('#roundNumber').html(counter + 1);
    }
    if(counter === 5){
        ui_alert('YOU WIN!');
        $('#winCount').html(++wins);
        return;
    }

    console.log('counter: ' + counter);
    if(counter === cpuSlice.length){
        console.log('num: ' + num);
        cpuSlice = cpuArray.slice(0, ++num);
        console.log('userArray:' + userArray);
        userArray = [];
        console.log('cpuSlice: ' + cpuSlice);
        goUpToPoint(cpuSlice);
        counter = 0;
    }
}

// Button presses
$('#a').mousedown(function(){
    if(!cpuLoop){
        buttonPress('a');
    }
});
$('#b').mousedown(function(){
    if(!cpuLoop) {
        buttonPress('b');
    }
});
$('#c').mousedown(function(){
    if(!cpuLoop){
        buttonPress('c');
    }
});
$('#d').mousedown(function(){
    if(!cpuLoop){
        buttonPress('d');
    }
});


// jQuery-UI alert for when the user has either won or lost
function ui_alert(output_msg) {

    $("<div></div>").html(output_msg).dialog({
        height: 150,
        width: 240,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        position: { my: "top", at: "center", of: window },
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "Ok",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    init();
                }
            }
        ]
    });
}

// Sound links
var aSoundCpu = new Howl({
    urls: ['https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3'],
    loop: false
});
var bSoundCpu = new Howl({
    urls: ['https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3'],
    loop: false
});
var cSoundCpu = new Howl({
    urls: ['https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3'],
    loop: false
});
var dSoundCpu = new Howl({
    urls: ['https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3'],
    loop: false
});
```

});

and [here is a link to the app on codepen](http://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/pen/avmeMK). Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to work OK for me for disabling user input during the computer's turn:

```
function goUpToPoint(arr){
    cpuLoop = true;
    console.log('cpuLoop: ' + cpuLoop);
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        cpuPlayList(arr[i], i);
    }
    //cpuLoop = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
        cpuLoop = false;
    }, arr.length * 500 + 1750);

    console.log('cpuLoop: ' + cpuLoop);

}
```

Then for the reset button, put this with your globals above function init()

```
timeoutsArray = [];
```

and make these function edits:

```
// Cpu plays sounds and lights up depending on cpuArray
function cpuPlayList(input, time){
    timeoutsArray.push(setTimeout(function(){
        if(input === 'a'){
            timeoutsArray.push(setTimeout(function(){
                aSoundCpu.play();
                $('#a').fadeOut(1).fadeIn(500);
            }, time * 500));
        } else if(input === 'b'){
            timeoutsArray.push(setTimeout(function(){
                bSoundCpu.play();
                $('#b').fadeOut(1).fadeIn(500);
            }, time * 500));
        } else if(input === 'c'){
            timeoutsArray.push(setTimeout(function(){
                cSoundCpu.play();
                $('#c').fadeOut(1).fadeIn(500);
            }, time * 500));
        } else if(input === 'd'){
            timeoutsArray.push(setTimeout(function(){
                dSoundCpu.play();
                $('#d').fadeOut(1).fadeIn(500);
            }, time * 500));
        }
    }, 1750));
};

// User presses restart button
$('.btn-warning').click(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < timeoutsArray.length; i++) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutsArray[i]);
    }
    timeoutsArray = [];
    init();
});
```

I think you were replacing some of your `looperX` variable values. Using an array to store all of your `setTimeout` functions guarantees that they all get cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `setTimeout` is an asynchronous function, which means that once you called it, the code after it continue as if it is done.

If you want the code to wait until the end of your loop, you need to invoke it at the end of the `setTimeout` function.

You could split your function in two (in your case it's the `goUpToPoint` function), something like this:

```
function first_part() {
    //Call setTimeout
    setTimeout(function() { some_function(); }, time);
}

function second_part() {
    // Rest of code...
}

function some_function() {
    //Delayed code...
    ...

    second_part();
}
```

Since you are calling your function a number of times, I would create a global counter that you can decrease at the end of each `setTimeout` call, and call the `second_part` function only if the counter is 0:

```
var global_counter = 0;

function first(num) {
    //Call setTimeout
    global_counter = num;

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() { some_function(); }, time);
    }
}

function second() {
    // Rest of code...
}

function some_function() {
    //Delayed code...
    ...

    // Decrease counter
    global_counter--;

    if (global_counter == 0) {
        second();
    }
}
```